# What is the probability of choosing one letter from the alphabet correctly, ten times in a row?

Tags: probability

Perhaps looked at best like a "lottery"? If you were assigned a ten letter word (MATHEMATIC) and all 26 letters of the alphabet were in a bag, what is the probability that all ten letters are selected? After each letter is drawn, it is put back into rotation (like the M and A, etc.). What are the "odds" of getting them all correct? For example, the "odds" of winning Powerball is 1 in 292,201,338 using 5/69 (white balls) + 1/26 (Powerballs). That said, the 5 white balls are not returned to the grab bag.

Edited to add: I have very basic understanding and education in probability and this is not for a class, nor am I a student. I guess the best way to classify the curiosity is for a puzzle? The order of drawing is not important. This is for an investigation (as odd as that sounds). Imagine a criminal sends a ten letter cipher, what is the probability that by drawing ten random scrabble tiles from a box of 26, you would select the ten tiles that share his name?

Comment: So what have you tried? Can you edit the question to show that? Also, do you need to get all $10$ letters in any order or does the order need to match as well?

Comment: In any order is fine. I think of it rather like pulling equal opportunity scrabble tiles out of a bag. The only thing I know how to do in this case is figure that the probability of me pulling an A is 1 in 26, a B is 1 in 26, etc. So, 1/26 * 1/26 * 1/26 (a total of ten times?). I'm not sure that I understand the steps though. Like, why do we multiply 1/26 and 1/26? I think I need help understanding the concept

Comment: The comment of @MathLover broaches an interesting point.  Normally, this problem is computed as $$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}}.$$  However, it is **critical** that $N,D$ be computed in a **consistent** manner.  That is, if you decide that it is easiest to regard the order that the letters are drawn in as important when computing $D$,  you must also construe order as important when computing $N$.

Comment: Please edit your query re: [1] What is the source of the problem (i.e. book/class/contest/random puzzle)? [2] What is your math education-sophistication; further, have you studied or are now studying Probability [3] If you are a Probability (or Combinatorics) student, you may have encountered theorems, worked examples, or solved problems that you regard as pertinent.  What are they?  Please do **not** respond with a comment.  Instead, please edit your query.

Comment: If you must get the 10 letters in correct sequence and you have one chance in 26 of correct letter on each draw then _probability_ is $(1/26)^{10}.$

Comment: @BruceET True, but the query asks merely for the probability that all 10 letters were selected, which indicates that if the letters are selected *out-of-order*, that is still regarded as successful.  The point of my $\frac{N}{D}$ comment is that even if order **does not count**, it might still be more convenient to **pretend** that it does, as long as the pretense is consistently maintained in the computations of both $N$ and $D$.

Comment: Thank you so much. If I were explaining that number to people with limited math education who may not understand the magnitude of the expression but seem to stare in shock when you tell them that something is "99%" or "less than "1%", how would you recommend explaining the low probability?

Comment: If your question/comment is addressed to me, I would explain that however the *possibilities* are (**consistently**) computed for $N,D$, it is natural to regard the probability as the number of favorable possibilities divided by the total number of possibilities.  Then, simply walk them through exactly how you computed $N$ and $D$.  Naturally, there is the underlying assumption that each *possibility* is equally likely.  This would explain, for example, why the chances of getting exactly 2 Heads in 3 coin tosses is $$\frac{\binom{3}{2}}{2^3}.$$

Comment: Excellent, thank you.